# In postgreSQL what char replaces one other char?

Tags: sql, postgresql

for example `'a%'` means all records that starts with a, no matter the length.

if I want only aa,ab,ac,ad,..... records with two letters that starts with `a`.  How do I write this condition?

postgresql guide doesn't show how to do it
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-string.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the underscore character to match any single character:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE column LIKE 'a_'
```

An alternative to this using the `%` wildcard operator is this:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE column LIKE 'a%' AND CHAR_LENGTH(column) = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Regex

```
select * 
from table_name 
where col_name ~'^a[A-Za-z]{1}$'
```

[`sqlfiddle-demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/eb757/2)

---

`^a[A-Za-z]{1}$` -  Will search for string with alphabets(*fetches alphabets w/ upper and lower case*) that starts with `a` and length 2

---

PostgreSQL Documentation for LIKE : - http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-LIKE

Comment: Your regex also matches `'a'` and `'aaa'`. You don't need the quantifier at all; `^a[A-Za-z]$` will only match a 2-character string.

Comment: @NickBarnes _Thanks for the heads-up!!_